# Bootstrap Carousal won't stop sliding after manually switching to slide 0

Tags: javascript

I'm running into a issue that bootstrap carousal start sliding automatically after I call the **.carousal(0)** method. My intention is to switch to slide 0 and stick it there (no automatic sliding should happen). I'm not sure what I missed.

Here's the steps to reproduce the issue (start with a W3CSchools demo):

From this demo: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_interval&stacked=h

Change initial javascript from

```
// Activate Carousel
$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: 500});
```

to

```
// Activate Carousel
$("#myCarousel").carousel(0);
$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: false});
```

Please advise, thanks!

---

Addition: What confuses me is why calling .carousal(0) would spoil my previous configuration of interval:false (in js) and data-interval="false" (in HTML)...

---

Update:

I just switched the two statements, and it worked. Like this:

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: false});
$("#myCarousel").carousel(0);
```

But still, I don't understand why the sequence of the javascript statements would affect the behavior. Can anyone answer that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work based on editing the demo you referenced.

```
// Activate Carousel
// $("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: 500});
$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: false});
$("#myCarousel").carousel(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes I can stop sliding by doing this, but I also need to run the .carousel(0) to stick to slide 0. Is there any way around? I need to stick to slide 0 and stop automatic sliding... What confuses me is that why calling .carousel(0) spoils my previous configuration of interval:false... Thanks.

Comment: Once the carousel is stopped, you can then set to index 0.